# How to make row hover cover the selection in datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, webix

I want to add a row hover to the Webix datatable using `hover` property, but it doesn't affect to the selected row by default.

I've tried to modify the `:hover` of the selection class, but the current notation works only for the hovered cell (while I need a hovered row):

```
<style>
  .bluehover{
      background:lightblue;
  }
  .webix_row_select:hover{
      background:lightblue !important;
  }
</style>
```

**[Snippet here](http://webix.com/snippet/14e993ab).**

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
.webix_row_select:hover{
    background:lightblue !important;
}
```

to

```
.webix_row_select *:hover{
    background:lightblue;
}
```

[Updated snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/9022e624)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution from @aisah is not up to date anymore.
Under webix 8 one only needs to set `hover:<css_class>` and define
`.<css_class>{background: <my_color>;}` without the `hover` selector.

[Snippet](https://snippet.webix.com/fkh09rud)

[Webix Documentation](https://docs.webix.com/api__ui.datatable_hover_config.html)